# how can i use yarn with PnP in an already angular project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, yarnpkg

In my existing angular project, i want to use yarn package manager with PnP instead of the npm. I changed the ng config with:

```
ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn
```

but the problem is when i run the command "yarn install" in the root of the project, it always adds node_modules and it seems something is wrong, how can i fix it?
angular/cli version is: 17.2.2 and
yarn version is: 4.1.0

Comment: include the actual error message in description. saying "something is wrong" doesn't give any helpful info to us.

Comment: Have a look at : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16980 It's not officialy supported bu there are some workarounds.